# Python convert text symbolic (string) matrix to sympy Matrix for determinant

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sympy

Suppose we want to compute a 4*4 matrix (say `A`) for determinant. If A is a **numerical matrix**, which reads

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[6,5,10,1],[7,10,7,6],[9,8,12,2],[4,9,11,3]])
np.linalg.det(A)
# 279.9999999999999
```

then we can easily get above result. For convenience, we adopt another method to get the same result as follows

```py
import numpy as np
a = '''
6 5 10 1
7 10 7 6
9 8 12 2
4 9 11 3
'''
A = np.matrix(a).reshape(4,4)
np.linalg.det(A)
# 279.9999999999999
```

i.e, first convert a string matrix to *np.matrix* and then compute its determinant.

Next, we assume the `4*4` matrix A is a **symbolic matrix**, e.g., A has some elements symbols w.r.t `x` . Then we can resort to the `sympy` package, which reads

```py
import sympy as sy
x = sy.symbols('x')
A = sy.Matrix((
[1, x, x ** 2, 0],
[0, 1, x, x ** 2],
[x ** 2, 0, 1, x],
[x, x ** 2, 0, 1]
))
sy.det(A)
## x**8 + x**4 + 1
```

Now my question is how can we  convert text symbolic (string) matrix to sympy Matrix for determinant as that in the **numerical case**? I have tried

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
x = sy.symbols('x')
a = '''
1 x x**2 0
0 1 x x**2
x**2 0 1 x
x x**2 0 1
'''
# A = sy.Matrix(np.matrix(a).reshape(4,4)) #Error!!!
# A = sy.Matrix(sy.MatrixSymbol(a,4,4)) #Unexpected!!!
# sy.det(A)
```

and both `A = sy.Matrix(np.matrix(a).reshape(4,4))` and `A = sy.Matrix(sy.MatrixSymbol(a,4,4))` are not working! How can I remedy this?

Comment: Don't take `np.matrix` as a model for what can be done with `sympy`.  It was written years ago to immitate MATLAB.  And is unique to that.  `sympy` has something called `simpify` to parse strings, returning expressions.  You'll need to study `sympy` docs some more.

Comment: Sometimes sympy symbols can be used in numpy arrays, returning an object dtype array.  I'm sure `np.matrix` was not written with that in mind, so I'm not surprised that raises an error (what error?)

Comment: @hpaulj Your points are well taken! Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is not a valid expression but if you split it into strings that are valid expressions then `sy.Matrix` will convert those:

```
In [12]: a = '''
    ...: 1 x x**2 0
    ...: 0 1 x x**2
    ...: x**2 0 1 x
    ...: x x**2 0 1
    ...: '''

In [13]: a.split()
Out[13]: 
['1',
 'x',
 'x**2',
 '0',
 '0',
 '1',
 'x',
 'x**2',
 'x**2',
 '0',
 '1',
 'x',
 'x',
 'x**2',
 '0',
 '1']
```

Now:

```
In [14]: Matrix(a.split()).reshape(4, 4)
Out[14]: 
⎡         2    ⎤
⎢1   x   x   0 ⎥
⎢              ⎥
⎢             2⎥
⎢0   1   x   x ⎥
⎢              ⎥
⎢ 2            ⎥
⎢x   0   1   x ⎥
⎢              ⎥
⎢     2        ⎥
⎣x   x   0   1 ⎦

In [15]: Matrix(a.split()).reshape(4, 4).det()
Out[15]: 
 8    4    
x  + x  + 1
```

Comment: Great, very impressive! Exactly what I need! @oscar-benjamin

Answer (score 2):

I can make a `sy.Matrix` from a list of lists of sympy expressions:

```
In [9]: a = \
   ...: [[1, x, x**2, 0],
   ...: [0, 1, x, x**2],
   ...: [x**2, 0, 1, x],
   ...: [x, x**2, 0, 1]]

In [10]: a
Out[10]: [[1, x, x**2, 0], [0, 1, x, x**2], [x**2, 0, 1, x], [x, x**2, 0, 1]]

In [11]: sy.Matrix(a)
Out[11]: 
Matrix([
[   1,    x, x**2,    0],
[   0,    1,    x, x**2],
[x**2,    0,    1,    x],
[   x, x**2,    0,    1]])

In [12]: M=_

In [13]: sy.det(M)
Out[13]: 
x**8 + x**4 + 1
```

---

`np.matrix(a)` (original string `a`), fails when trying to parse terms like `x`.  It "knows" nothing about sympy and its symbols.

```
     24 for col in trow:
     25     temp = col.split()
---> 26     newrow.extend(map(ast.literal_eval, temp))
     27 if count == 0:
     28     Ncols = len(newrow)
```

It iterates on rows, and within that the split strings, using standard python `ast` library to parse them.